# Disappearing button in HTML

Tags: javascript, css, html

I wrote a simple input field with a button in it. Code is as given below.

```css
form {
  width: 50%;
}


/* Style the search field */

.add-on {
  position: relative;
}

.add-on input {
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 0;
}

.add-on button {
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 0;
  top: 2px;
  right: 3px;
  height: 33px;
  width: 60px;
  z-index: 2;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<form class="navbar-form my-2 my-lg-0 ml-auto" role="search">
  <div class="input-group add-on">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="srch-term" id="srch-term">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Search</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

As you can see, when I click in input field, button disappears. When I click outside that form, it reappears. But I don't want it to disappear when clicked on input field. How can I do that?

Comment: I'm fetching this error... {
  "message": "Script error.",
  "filename": "",
  "lineno": 0,
  "colno": 0
}

Comment: hmmm. I think the button is disappearing because. the text box is widens out past the button. Reduce the width of the text input and it may work...

Comment: The button is still there - it's just covered by the input field. You can see that the field is *below* the button normally and then it appears on top when you click there.

Comment: @AjayKulkarni it's not good practice to show **search button** using `position: absolute` on `input` field. Suppose you have long content in your `input` then your **search button** will overlap your content. Currently it's happening in your code.

Comment: Can you explain WHY you want the button to overlap the input? Maybe we can come up with another solution.

Comment: Add `padding-right: 45px;` to `.add-on input` to fix the problem @HassanSiddiqui is describing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `z-index` while focus

```
 input:focus ~ .btn-primary {
     z-index: 100;
 }
```

```css
form {
  width: 50%;
}


/* Style the search field */

.add-on {
  position: relative;
}

.add-on input {
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 0;
}

.add-on button {
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 0;
  top: 2px;
  right: 3px;
  height: 33px;
  width: 60px;
  z-index: 2;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 5px;
}

 input:focus ~ .btn-primary {
     z-index: 100;
 }
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<form class="navbar-form my-2 my-lg-0 ml-auto" role="search">
  <div class="input-group add-on">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="srch-term" id="srch-term">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Search</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 7):

Set `z-index: 1` on `#srch-term` element

Answer (score 5):

Change the `z-index` in the `.add-on button` CSS rule to `3`.

```
.add-on button {
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 0;
  top: 2px;
  right: 3px;
  height: 33px;
  width: 60px;
  z-index: 3;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just give a higher value to the `z-index` of your button. Probably the input highlight that places a div upon it

```css
form {
  width: 50%;
}


/* Style the search field */

.add-on {
  position: relative;
}

.add-on input {
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 0;
}

.add-on button {
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 0;
  top: 2px;
  right: 3px;
  height: 33px;
  width: 60px;
  z-index: 5;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<form class="navbar-form my-2 my-lg-0 ml-auto" role="search">
  <div class="input-group add-on">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="srch-term" id="srch-term">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Search</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set `position: relative` to the button

```css
form {
  width: 50%;
}


/* Style the search field */

.add-on {
  position: relative;
}

.add-on input {
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 0;
}

.add-on button {
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 0;
  top: 2px;
  right: 3px;
  height: 33px;
  width: 60px;
  z-index: 2;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="navbar-form my-2 my-lg-0 ml-auto" role="search">
  <div class="input-group add-on">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="srch-term" id="srch-term">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Search</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: that brings button outside input field. I want it to stay inside input field.

Answer (score 0):

As others are saying, the input field covers the button when it is focused.
Try to set a permanent z-index on your input and button and make the z-index for button higher than the input's.

```css
form {
    width: 50%;
  }


  /* Style the search field */

  .add-on {
    position: relative;
  }

  .add-on input {
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 0;
    z-index: 1020;
  }

  .add-on button {
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 0;
    top: 2px;
    right: 3px;
    height: 33px;
    width: 60px;
    z-index: 2;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 5px;
    z-index: 1021;
  }
```

```html
 <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<form class="navbar-form my-2 my-lg-0 ml-auto" role="search">
  <div class="input-group add-on">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="srch-term" id="srch-term">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Search</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem goes away if i add z-index: 1 to input and z-index: 3 to button. Can't figure out why but z-index: 2 on button doesen't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

simply add `z-index` to input. the value is more than -1 and less than the button `z-index`

```
/* Style the search field */

.add-on input {
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 0;
  z-index: 0
}

.add-on button {
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 0;
  top: 2px;
  right: 3px;
  height: 33px;
  width: 60px;
  z-index: 2;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

Comment: This is no different to any other answer given.

Answer (score 0):

> **Solution 1 - Change `z-index: 2` to `z-index: 3` in `.add-on button`, but if your content increase the search button will overlap with content.**

```css
form {
  width: 50%;
}


/* Style the search field */

.add-on {
  position: relative;
}

.add-on input {
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 0;
}

.add-on button {
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 0;
  top: 2px;
  right: 3px;
  height: 33px;
  width: 60px;
  z-index: 3;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<form class="navbar-form my-2 my-lg-0 ml-auto" role="search">
  <div class="input-group add-on">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="srch-term" id="srch-term">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Search</button>
  </div>  
</form>
```

> **Solution 2 - Remove `position: absolute`, `top: 2px`, `right: 3px`, `z-index: 2` from `.add-on button` and update `height: 33px;` to `height: 38px;` in `.add-on button`, it'll display search next to input field and it'll not overlap content.**

```css
form {
  width: 50%;
}


/* Style the search field */

.add-on {
  position: relative;
}

.add-on input {
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 0;
}

.add-on button {
  border-radius: 0;
  height: 38px;
  width: 60px;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<form class="navbar-form my-2 my-lg-0 ml-auto" role="search">
  <div class="input-group add-on">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="srch-term" id="srch-term">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Search</button>
  </div>  
</form>
```